# everypage + textblock not working correctly

Tags: counters, textpos, everypage

I was just setting up chapter marks at the edge of every page in my thesis and came to an issue with the `\thechapter` counter being off by one. I've managed to fix the issue by checking the [ltshipout](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/base/ltshipout-doc.pdf) documentation and trying a different hook. In case someone runs into a similar issue here is a minimal working example.

Cheers

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\TPGrid[0mm,0mm]{10}{12}

\newcommand*{\AddEverypageHook}[1]{%
 % \AddToHook{shipout/background}{\put(1in,-1in){#1}}}  % This does not work
   \AddToHook{shipout/before}{#1}                       % This is the fix
}                       
 
\begin{document}
\AddEverypageHook{
    \textblockcolour{black}
    \begin{textblock}{1}(0,0)
        \vspace{10.5mm}
        \hspace{7mm}\huge{\sffamily\fontseries{b}\selectfont\thechapter}
        \vspace{10.5mm}
    \end{textblock}
}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Bar}
\end{document}
```

Comment: hm, it looks a bit dubious to do typesetting in the \shipout/before hook. Why do you use textblock at all here? you can simply place your text directly into the the \put command.

Comment: `\documentclass{book}
\AddToHook{shipout/background}{\put(1in,-1in){\huge\sffamily\bfseries\thechapter}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Bar}
\end{document}`

Comment: I'm using the textbox because I'm painting the background black with `\textblockcolour`, looks like I forgot to copy it in the example. Also, because I didn't know about the thumbs package. :)